# How to patch JNI library to call functions on Linux

Tags: android, patching

According to [this post](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/12/adventures-in-video-conferencing-part-4.html) it is possible to run functions inside a shared library **so long as they do not have a dependency on the JVM**

> It works by patching the .dynamic ELF section to remove unnecessary dependencies by replacing DT_NEEDED tags with DT_DEBUG tags. We also needed to remove constructors and deconstructors by changing the DT_FINI_ARRAYSZ and DT_INIT_ARRAYSZ to zero.

So how could this be implemented?

Thanks